# Test code to compare jackson Stream vs Map - Is this working right?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a server side application that I am profiling using **`VisualVM`** that makes use of Streaming API.

However, since there are a lot of factors in that code I also made a toy example to compare streaming vs mapping. 
I have a feeling that something may be off in that there is a lot of randomness in the results.

Is it the measuring? Would using other types of typers make a difference? Is it that there is something that is multi-threaded I don't know about?

Currently I am writing to `NUL` file object the windows equivalent of `dev/null`. I am running this on `high` priority in case the operating system may affect it.

**Toy Example Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class TestStreamingMapping {

    public final static int NUM_SIMULATED_CATALOGS = 10000;
    public final static int CATALOG_SIZE = 1000;                //1000 Items in CATALOG, 500 requests per second
    public final static boolean WRITE_TO_FILE = false;          //Write to file, or write to string
    public final static boolean DEBUG_PRINT_100_CHAR = false;   //Print out part of string to see all ok
    public static final String mappingFile = "mapping.txt";     //If writing to file, where?
    public static final String streamingFile = "streaming.txt"; //If streaming to file, where?
    public static final boolean PRINT_INTERMEDIATE_RESULTS = false;

    public static TreeMap<Long,Double> iterationPercentages = new TreeMap<Long,Double>();

    ObjectMapper  mapper= new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
    JsonGenerator g;

    public static long totalCountStream = 0, totalCountMap = 0;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {       

        System.out.println("Press enter when profiler is connected...");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Starting iterations of JSON generation.");
        double percentage;

        for(long i=0; i<NUM_SIMULATED_CATALOGS; i++)
        {
            performTest();  
            percentage = (totalCountStream*100.0d / totalCountMap);
            iterationPercentages.put(i, percentage);

            if(!PRINT_INTERMEDIATE_RESULTS && i%100 == 0)System.out.print(i+"-");
        }

        System.out.println("Total Streaming API:        " + totalCountStream + "    ns.");
        System.out.println("Total Mapping API:      " + totalCountMap + "   ns.");
        System.out.println("Total Stream(as % of map):  " +  totalCountStream*100.0d / totalCountMap  + "   %\r\n" );

        System.out.println("Iteration\tStreamPercent");
        for(Entry<Long, Double> entry : iterationPercentages.entrySet())
            if(entry.getKey() % 20 ==0)
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t\t" + Math.round(entry.getValue())  + "%" );

    }

    public static void performTest()
    {
        TestStreamingMapping test = new TestStreamingMapping(); 
        long time1, time2;
        double percentage = 0;

        try {       
            long starttime1 = System.nanoTime();
            test.streamingToFile();
            totalCountStream+=time1=System.nanoTime() - starttime1;

            long starttime2 = System.nanoTime();
            test.objectMapping();
            totalCountMap+=time2=System.nanoTime() - starttime2;

            percentage = (time1*100.0d / time2);

            if(PRINT_INTERMEDIATE_RESULTS)
            {
                System.out.println("Streaming API:      " + time1 + "   ns.");
                System.out.println("Mapping API:        " + time2 + "   ns.");
                System.out.println("Stream(as % of map):    " + percentage  + " %" );
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------\r\n");       

            }           

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }

    public String[] numbers;
    public ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public TestStreamingMapping()
    {
        numbers=new String[62];
        for(int i=0; i<60; i++) numbers[i] = String.valueOf(Math.random()*i);

        for(int i=0; i<60; i++) arrayList.add(String.valueOf(Math.random()*i));
    }


    public void initializeGenerator(StringWriter writer) throws IOException
    {
        if(WRITE_TO_FILE)
            g = f.createGenerator(new File(mappingFile), JsonEncoding.UTF8);
        else
            g = f. createGenerator(writer);
    }


    public void objectMapping() throws IOException
    {       
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        initializeGenerator(writer);

        for(int j=0; j<CATALOG_SIZE; j++)
            mapper.writeValue(g, this); 

        g.close();
        writer.close();     

        if(DEBUG_PRINT_100_CHAR)
        System.out.println(writer.toString().substring(0,100));
    }




    public void streamingToFile() throws IOException
    {

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        initializeGenerator(writer);

        for(int j=0; j<CATALOG_SIZE; j++)
        {
             g.writeStartObject();  
             g.writeFieldName("numbers_streaming");  
             g.writeStartArray(); 
             for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) g.writeString(numbers[i]); 
             g.writeEndArray();

             g.writeFieldName("arrayList");  g.writeStartArray(); 
             for(String num: arrayList) g.writeString(num); 
             g.writeEndArray();

             g.writeEndObject(); 
        }

        g.close();
        writer.close();     

        if(DEBUG_PRINT_100_CHAR)
        System.out.println(writer.toString().substring(0,100));

    }

}
```

The below code is simulating a service that would generate a JSON catalog document with 1000 Prouct Objects. The hotspot obviously is the serialization of the products (`streamToFile()` vs `objectMapping()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, couple of things.

Most importantly, you should create just one `JsonFactory` instance, similar to how you reuse `ObjectMapper`. Reuse of these objects is one of key things for performance with Jackson. See [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance) for more ideas.

Another thing to consider is that use of `File` adds I/O overhead, which should be about the same for both approaches, and diminishes difference in actual processing times. You may want to separate this to see how much of time is spent on file access. I realize that this may be bogus file (as per note on how OS deals with that), but even without physical overhead, OS typically incurs some syscall overhead.

And then one general aspect is that when measuring performance on JVM, you always need to keep in mind warm-up time: you should always warm up tests for multiple seconds (5 or 10 seconds minimum), as well as run actual test for sufficient time (like 30 seconds or more), to get more stable results.
This is where test frameworks can help, as they can actually statistically measure things and figure out when results stabilize enough to be meaningful.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Based on your comments I updated my code. If you have time could you have a look in case something still looks off? Thanks!

Comment: Looks better! I think one last suggestion is to just call `performTest()` a few times before taking any measurements: ideally based on time, like running for 5 seconds, then start measurements. Numbers from first couple of calls will be arbitrary, and skew results quite a bit (since they can take 10-100 times longer than steady state).